# Nginx reverse proxy for two webapplications

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have two applications.

- **Laravel Application** - Being just a dynamic website. Does not have
  data-knowledge. All the data gets fetched from the second application
  using AJAX-requests. Runs on `127.0.0.1:8000`.
- **Rust Application** - A web-application containing all the business
  logic and data-access. Runs on `127.0.0.1:8080`.

Both applications need to be accessible from the URL `example.com`.
For this I want to use Nginx Reverse Proxy. I am already able to reroute all requests to my Laravel Application.

```
events {}
http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        # Website
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }
        
    }
}
```

While the Laravel Application works, I need actually need the following Nginx configuration:

- Specific pages like `/news`, `/`, `/about`,`/contact`,... should be redirected to `127.0.0.1:8000`.
- Note: The pages above can contain GET-parameters like e.g `/news?article=abc`.
- ALL other requests need to be redirected to `127.0.0.1:8080`.
- Note: 127.0.0.1:8080 can often contain a subdomain. But this subdomain needs to act like a wildcard and is unknown at the time of configuration. Example: `bussiness1.example.com`, `bussiness2.example.com`, `businnesX.example.com`,...

The subdomain returns a personalized page for which an unlimited amount of businesses can request for on example.com.

How would I achieve this configuration? I was thinking something like this?

```
#PSEUDO
events {}
http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        # Website
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }
        location /news {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }
        location /about {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }

        # Application
        location * {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }

    }
}
```

**Edit regarding Tero's answer:**
I need a kind of wildcard for subdomains.

```
 # Application catch-all
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://$subdomain.$application;
    }
```

abc.example.com needs to go to abc.127.0.0.1:8080
def.example.com needs to go to def.127.0.0.1:8080
...

I know an IP can't have a subdomain but don't worry about that. I solved that with virtual hosts.

**Edit 2 - Pass subdomain of request to proxy_pass:**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name *.website.com;
        server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.website\.com$;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://$subdomain.vhost.local:8080;
        }
    }
```

Is this the correct way to redirect dynamicxxx.website.com to dynamicxxx.vhost.local:8080?

Comment: i think you have to replace star with tilde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design is a bit complex and therefore fragile. However, you can try the following. I added `upstream` blocks so that the different `proxy_pass` destinations are more readable.

```
upstream website {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

upstream application {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    server_name example.com *.example.com;

    listen 80;

    # Application catch-all
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://application;
    }

    # Website
    location = / {
        proxy_pass http://website;
    }

    location /news {
        proxy_pass http://website;
    }

    location /about {
        proxy_pass http://website;
    }
}
```

The `=` character means an exact match on the URI, and is the first priority in nginx lookup process as described in [nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

An alternative approach is to use regular expression:

```
server {
    server_name example.com *.example.com;

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://application;
    }

    location ~ ^(?:/|/news|/about) {
        proxy_pass http://website;
    }
}
```

The `server_name example.com *.example.com` tells nginx to process all requests to main domain and any subdomain with these rules.

If the website request rules need to apply only to `example.com`, then you need to define another `server` block with `server_name *.example.com` and application rules only.

**Edit**

Yes, subdomain can be captured to a variable like that, and used in `proxy_pass` destination. You need to have all domains in single `server_name` line:

```
server_name example.com ~^(?<subdomain>[^.]+)\.example\.com;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! This is getting close. However, the Catch-all for the application also needs to handle subdomains. Is a kind of wildcard possible? See post edit.

Comment: Then you need to do a second `server` block for the subdomains with `server_name *.example.com`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Explained it a lot. If you could only look again at my second edit? Regarding the subdomain wildcard.

Comment: I'm really close mate. Only the subdomain wildcard remains.

Comment: I added a `server_name` example.